# UnexpectedRollBackException in Spring inner transaction

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have two classes:

```
@Service
@Transaction
class A {
    public void method1() {
        private B;

        try {
            save1()
            b.method2()
        } catch (SqlException e) {
            doSomeThing();
        }

       @Autowired
       public setB(){
         this.B = B;
       }
    }
}

@Service
class B {

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void method2(){
        save2()
        throw new SqlException();
    }

}
```

I got an `SqlException` as expected, but also an `UnexpectedRollBackException`, and the program stops. 
I want to know why the data persisted by save2() is not rolled back?

Is it a problem with outer transaction?

UPDATE: I tried catching `UnexpectedRollBackException` in class A and everything works fine. But I still need some kind of explanation why I get the exception? I suppose the outer transaction should be suspended when the inner transaction begins, so why the rollback is unexpected for the outer transaction?

Thanks.

Comment: Read Ilya Dyoshin's answer. There is only one transaction running on both method invocations because `B` is not a managed bean, so no interceptors applied to  `B#method2`, and that includes transactional interceptor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: you are not injecting the instance of B into class A  via spring. i.e. your b is not managed by spring => this leads to the behaviour: Spring is ignoring the `@Transactional` annotation on method.

Second if you don't want to rollback on `SqlException` you have to specify  `noRollbackFor=SqlException.class`

UPDATE: after clarification, the call is happening on managed bean. But the problem that expected behaviour - transaction inside of transaction is not supported in general by the transaction management system out of the box. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.11.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html#REQUIRES_NEW

Unless the details on that system are provided it is impossible to step forward. Out of content the NESTED transaction propagation could be better, then REQUIRES_NEW, because it is making a rollback point for the external transaction and starts new one.

Comment: Sorry but class B is annoted with @Service, so it's a managed bean

Comment: @brest1007  but you are not injecting it - you are creating an instance of it  in runtime, and thus no spring's "magic" is applie. i.e. all annotations are ignored.

Comment: ok you are good. But in fact, I used setter injection for B, and it still does not work. the "new" was a mistake when i wrote the question

Comment: can you provide information on your transaction manager.  the Spring team stated that suspension of transaction (from REQUIRES_NEW propagation) has limited support in runtime:  Actual transaction suspension will not work out-of-the-box on all transaction managers. This in particular applies to JtaTransactionManager, which requires the javax.transaction.TransactionManager to be made available it to it (which is server-specific in standard Java EE).

Comment: So i would suggest to try NESTED transaction propagation.  Actual creation of a nested transaction will only work on specific transaction managers. Out of the box, this only applies to the JDBC DataSourceTransactionManager when working on a JDBC 3.0 driver. Some JTA providers might support nested transactions as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simliar scenario like this and  resolved it using `propagation = Propagation.NESTED` from where the second `method` is calling. rewrite the code as mentioned below and try.

```
@Service
class A {
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { HibernateException.class}, propagation = Propagation.NESTED)
    public void method1() {
        private B;

        try {
            save1()
            b.method2()
        } catch (SqlException e) {
            doSomeThing();
        }

       @Autowired
       public setB(){
         this.B = B;
       }
    }
}
```

Note: `Transactional` is used in method level for `class A` with `propagation nested` . `Class B` shown below.

```
@Service
class B {

   @Transactional(rollbackFor = {Exception.class}, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void method2(){
        save2()
        throw new SqlException();
    }

}
```

This has resolved the issue in my case.